# Jest detects open handle DNSCHANNEL if node package got is used

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm programming server in `Node.js v12.18.3`, using `Express` framework. My code uses `Jest` for unit testing. In one of my module, I've used the `got` package. But it's not used in any unit test.

I've designed the following minimal test:

```
const { app } = require('../app');
const { mongoose, database } = require('../database/database');
const api_dict = require("../api_dictionary");
var User = require('../models/user');

describe("===== POST " + api_dict.users_create + " Tests ===== ", () => {

    var db;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await mongoose.connect(database, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        db = mongoose.connection;
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await db.close();
    });

    test("Create user", () => {
    });
});
```

I'm using `jest --detectOpenHandles` command to detect open handles. Jest detected one:

```
npm test

> jetfire@0.0.0 test E:\Projects\github\project_name
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --detectOpenHandles

 PASS  tests/tests.js (8.118 s)
  ===== POST /user/create Tests =====
    √ Create user (1 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.196 s
Ran all test suites.

Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  DNSCHANNEL

      at new CacheableLookup (node_modules/cacheable-lookup/source/index.js:75:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:29:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/types.js:16:16)
```

How to ensure that this handle is closed when all unit tests are ran?

Comment: Did you figure out how to close this handle?

Comment: @NireshPrabhu: No

Comment: one possible solution is to use `--forceExit` which will terminate the connection , not ideal but can help in some cases